# Android debugging

Tags: android, debugging

since the latest version of my Android application I got some bug reports (via email) that my application doesn't work anymore. It does not crash but doesn't work anymore. Only a few users (<0.05%) have this problem. I don't see any similarities (same phone/provider/...).

Has anyone an idea how I can tackle this problem and find the bug?

If I publish a debug version of the application, is there any tool that the end-user can use to grab the logcat output and send it per email or...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you incorporate a logging feature on your app, even the retail one. Make a log of critical/fatal errors, but try to minimize the log size (e.g. erasing it periodically or only logging really really critical errors). This way you can request such logs for such users, without having them install a new version of the app, and having them to recreate the erros, since sometimes recreating the whole situation in which such crashes occur is close to impossible, or that it doesn't happen for some other reason in a debug version.

You can also incorporate a function that sends you the log periodically, or just request it to the users.

I don't know any tool other than ADK to grab the logcat...

Comment: I implemented something close to what you proposed. I replaced all `Log.d` (and others) to `MyLog.d`. The latter prints the string to logcat but also stores the last 400 prints. When someone reports a problem (by email) I include those logs. I first used `READ_LOGS` permission to retrieve the logs but this permission is presented as 'Retrieval of sensitive personal info' which caused multiple 1 star ratings.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best debugging tool available is the ACRA library.

Below are few links, which will help you to use this library.

1) http://code.google.com/p/acra/downloads/detail?name=acra-4.2.3.zip&can=2&q=

2)http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

Let me know if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It is easy to integrate this tool into project - everything works well after the 1st try. No pain at all.